# Web API Post not returning response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API that gets call by this method:

```
public async Task<Model> AddModel(string token, Model newModel)
{
    HttpContent content = await HttpHelper.Request(token, baseUrl, url, newModel, HttpRequestType.POST);
    return await content.ReadAsAsync<Model>();
}
```

The Web API is successfully called and I can add a Model. This is the Web API method that gets called:

```
[Route("webapi/models/addModel")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ModelDto> AddWithoutResetingDefault(ModelDto newModel)
{
    ModelService modelService = new ModelService();
    return modelService.AddModel(newModel);
}
```

The problem is after the successful add, it doesn't return to the calling code anymore (I have a breakpoint that doesn't get hit). There are no console errors in the browser, I enclosed in a try-catch the calling code and the called code but there were no exceptions thrown.

Also, after the first click to add, if I try to refresh the browser, it takes a really long time to reload the browser (I don't know if being async has something to do with it).

Answer (score 0):

**(I don't know if being async has something to do with it) - Yes it has**

your Api method

```
public async Task<ModelDto> AddWithoutResetingDefault(ModelDto newModel)
{
    ModelService modelService = new ModelService();
    return modelService.AddModel(newModel);
}
```

is marked as Async method, but the code inside is Sync. And that is the problem, if your `modelService.AddModel(newModel)`; is async, then do
 `return await modelService.AddModel(newModel);`

if its not then there is no point in making the `AddWithoutResetingDefault` 
method async, hence remove Aysnc and simply do a sync method like

```
 public ModelDto AddWithoutResetingDefault(ModelDto newModel)
    {
        ModelService modelService = new ModelService();
        return modelService.AddModel(newModel);
    }
```